# Manipulating an element's data in vue 2 (V-Model)

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have multiple  elements on my component's template, and the data for it is imported from another JS file. I need to have a button, that when clicked, will change the contents of the h1 heading. I don't fully understand how v-model works, like how to bind it inside a for loop. Please take a look at my example code.

```
<button @click.prevent="changeData">Click Me!</button>
<div v-for="heading in headings" :key="heading.id">
  <h1>{{ heading.title }}<h1>
</div>
```

```js
import { dataA, dataB } from '../data.js';
headings = dataA

export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
               headings
            }
           methods: {
               changeData(){
                  headings = dataB
                  } 
}
        },
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Oops added that in the example

Comment: ok, change `headings = dataB` to `this.headings = dataB`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Oh my god amn't I dumb. Shouldn't have learned Vue 3 first lol. Tysm!